# How to display data from a weather api in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, openweathermap

I am trying to create a simple weather app using the open weather api to help learn React.
However I am unable to display any data in the DOM.

Wondered if anyone could help and explain to me what I need to do so i know for future! Thanks.

```
import React from 'react'
import Titles from './Titles'
import axios from "axios"


const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_API_KEY

class Display extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
        };
  async componentDidMount() {
       const URL = (`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=taipei,tw&APPID=${API_KEY}`)
       let response = await axios.get(URL);
       let data  = response.data;
       this.setState({ data });
   }




    render(){
    let data = this.state.data
        return(
            <div>
            <Titles />
           <p>{data.description}</p>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Display;
```

On this example of code I have an error message saying:
  cannot read property 'description' of null.

The following is the api I am trying to access and display temp, description, city etc:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 121.56,
        "lat": 25.04
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 304.08,
        "pressure": 1001,
        "humidity": 79,
        "temp_min": 302.59,
        "temp_max": 305.93
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 4.1,
        "deg": 90
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 75
    },
    "dt": 1565143170,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7949,
        "message": 0.0097,
        "country": "TW",
        "sunrise": 1565126625,
        "sunset": 1565174130
    },
    "timezone": 28800,
    "id": 1668341,
    "name": "Taipei",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `data.weather.description`?

Comment: At the first render you try getting `description` of `data` `{data.description}`. But `data` is null that why you get the error

Comment: data.weather.description give me the error: cannot read 'weather' as null.

Comment: I changed data to data: ' ' and nothing is displayed on the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initial state is,

```
data: null
```

And first time component renders with it's default state. So accessing `data.description` will give you error because `data=null`.

You should always check if data present when working with `componentDidMount`.

Try this,

```
<p>{data && data.weather.length > 0 && data.weather.description}</p>
```

---

**Update**

By looking at your response data.

```
"weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10d"
        }
    ]
```

`weather` node is array. You can do this,

```
<p>{data && data.weather.length > 0 && data.weather[0].description}</p>   //display first record
```

If you want to show all the records, you can do this,

```
{data && data.weather.length > 0 && data.weather.map(weather => {
   return <p>{weather.description}</p>
})}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djdivj)

Comment: Ok I have tried this however the issue is the same. The state of data changes to the api data, however data is not showing in the DOM.

Comment: Please update your question's code to show us how you do

Comment: Thanks that has worked and now shows the description. The second piece of code you sent doesn't show all records however. Thanks!